# Probability of 5 people choosing a unique person randomly

Tags: probability

There are 5 people in a circle and on the count of 3 they will all point at someone randomly and simultaneously.They cannot point to themselves.

What is the probability of them all pointing at someone different?

---

I appreciate this is probably quite a straightforward question for those who know probability.

I can see the total variations is $4^5$.
What I don't know how to work out is how many of these variations give an answer to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D_n$, [Derangment](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) is a permutation  in which none of the objects appear in their "natural" (i.e., ordered) place.

What we are looking for would be

$$\frac{D_5}{4^5}=\frac{44}{4^5}=\frac{11}{4^4}.$$

Comment: It should be $\frac{11}{4^4}$, not $\frac{11}{4^6}$

Comment: oops, thanks. i made a mistake.

Comment: I have been trying to wrap my head around this derangement and how it applies to this problem. My issue is that the order is allowed to be natural though. ABCDE is a possible answer.

Comment: they cannot point to themselves right?

Comment: no, I meant A to B to C etc.

Comment: Ok I see now, the order is who they pointed to. Sorry and many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Let us label the people A through E, and let $(A,B)$ mean that A pointed to B.

In order for everyone to point and be pointed to, we require that the 5 people be divided up into closed loops, for instance $(A,B)(B,C)(C,D)(DA)$ would be a closed loop of 4 members.  In a closed loop of $n$ members, there are $(n-1)!$ possible orderings of the loop.

One possibility is for everyone to be in a 5 member loop.  In a 5 member loop, there are $4!=24$ possible ways to divide the people into ordered pairs.

It is impossible to have a 4 member loop, as that would force the fifth person to be in a loop by himself.

It is possible to have a 3 member loop and a 2 member loop.  There are $\frac{5!}{3!2!}=10$ ways of dividing the people into those loops, and for each of those 10 ways, there are 2 ways of ordering the 3 person loop, for a total of 20 possibilities of a 3 member loop and a 2 member loop.

If we have a 2 member loop, we could either divide the 3 remaining people into a 3 member loop or into at least 2 loops.  We already considered the possibility of a 3 and 2 member loop, and dividing 3 people into 2 or more loops would result in having a 1 person loop.  Therefore this adds no new possibilities.

It is impossible to have a 1 member loop.

Therefore, we found a total of 44 scenarios where each person points to someone else.  The probability is $\frac{44}{4^5}=\frac{11}{256}$

Comment: +1 thanks for the answer. Given answer to Siong Thye Goh as he answered first.